# How to implement association class?

Tags: c#

What is association classes, how to implement the association classes for this given model.
See the screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically:

```cs
class GeoObjectPart
{
  public int Category { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<GeoObjectPart> Parts { get; set; } 
}

class GeoObject
{
 public int ObjectType { get; set; } // do not use Type as a property name!
 public long Id { get; set; }
 public IEnumerable<GeoObjectPart> Parts { get; set; } 
}
```

And `Line, Point, Area` inherits `GeoObjectPart` class.

BTW, `GeoObject.Type` and `GeoObjectPart.Category` means the same? In such case consider some redesign because you can use single class instead of both `GeoObject and GeoObjectPart`

Also, few recommendations:

- mark base class as abstract so avoid to instantiate classes which are designed to be a base
- name base class with prefix `base`, like `GeoObjectBase`
- consider interface for `GeoObjectBase` class
- if this possible avoid `public setters` so instances would be immutable